# Why is $\delta[an]=\frac 1 a \delta[n]$ in discrete time?

Tags: discrete-signals, impulse-response

> Why is $\delta[an]=\frac 1 a \delta[n]$ in discrete time? Prove.

Hi, I want to prove it but I don’t know on what facts to rely. In continuous time we have integral and dt in that integral that turns to be dt/a for continuous time delta function. But in discrete time, we don’t have dt. So how to prove it then?

Comment: Where did you find that "identity"?

Comment: Here: http://pilot.cnxproject.org/content/collection/col10064/latest/module/m34566/latest

Comment: This is a property of the Dirac distribution and follows from a substitution of the integration variable. It does not have an equivalent for the Kronecker unit impulse.

Comment: Thanks! Marking as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually good that you couldn't prove it because the claim is wrong. Note that in discrete time we have $\delta[n]=1$ for $n=0$ and $\delta[n]=0$ for $n\neq 0$. So if $a\neq 0$, you simply get $\delta[an]=\delta[n]$ (note that $a$ must be an integer for this to make sense). If $a=0$ then $\delta[an]=1$ (for all $n$).

Comment: Thanks Matt. Let’s wait for one more opinion before I mark your answer as the right answer, since I already saw a few things I considered to be wrong and meanwhile my teacher proves I’m the only wrong time after time. Thanks for your answer, it raises my level of confident (besides seemingly being true).